# Detecting changes in multivariate time series

Tags: time-series, multivariate-regression

I have the following problem I am trying to solve. I am hoping to pick your brain on the possible solutions.

I have (say) 10000 machines, each one spit out a number for me each day; I have collected these numbers for over 2 years (>700 observations) and I know the numbers from different machines are correlated whereas numbers from the same machine are autocorrelated with some seasonal effects. I also know that, at certain known point in time last year, someone made changes to some (not all) of my machines at different time which may have an impact on the number they spit out.

What I would like to do is to calculate the impact of the changes to my machines - essentially, a what-if analysis if the changes did not occur. What are my strategies of solving this problem?

Regards,

-Z